# Create unique array when merging two array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, lodash

I want to merge two arrays of objects. One key will be the same in those 2 arrays.

Here is the sample data:

```
var a = ['Europe', 'Africa', 'Antarctica'];

var b = [
 {id: 11, warehouse_name: 'Europe', input_qty: 200, total_amt: 4000},
 {id: 12, warehouse_name: 'Africa', input_qty: 150, total_amt: 3500},
 {id: 13, warehouse_name: 'Africa', input_qty: 20, total_amt: 500},
 {id: 14, warehouse_name: 'Antarctica', input_qty: 50, total_amt: 1500}
];
```

My expected output should be:

```
var c = [
 {warehouse_name: 'Europe', pack: [{id: 11, warehouse_name: 'Europe', input_qty: 200, total_amt: 4000}]},
 {warehouse_name: 'Africa', pack: [{id: 12, warehouse_name: 'Africa', input_qty: 150, total_amt: 3500}, {id: 13, warehouse_name: 'Africa', input_qty: 20, total_amt: 500}]},
 {warehouse: 'Antarctica', pack: [{id: 14, warehouse_name: 'Antarctica', input_qty: 50, total_amt: 1500}]}
];
```

How can i achieve this in javascript using lodash or without using lodash. Any solution is appreciated.

Comment: Unique array with immutated original object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it using array `Array.prototype.map()` method. Traverse the `a` array using map and filter b array by `a` arrays value using `Array.prototype.filter` method.

```js
const a = ['Europe', 'Africa', 'Antarctica'];

const b = [
  { id: 11, warehouse_name: 'Europe', input_qty: 200, total_amt: 4000 },
  { id: 12, warehouse_name: 'Africa', input_qty: 150, total_amt: 3500 },
  { id: 13, warehouse_name: 'Africa', input_qty: 20, total_amt: 500 },
  { id: 14, warehouse_name: 'Antarctica', input_qty: 50, total_amt: 1500 },
];

const ret = a.map((x) => ({
  warehouse_name: x,
  pack: b.filter((y) => y.warehouse_name === x),
}));
console.log(ret);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `_.groupBy()` create an object (`byWarehouse`) of items by `warehouse_name` from array `b`. Now map array `a`, and take the items from `byWarehouse` to create the object:

```js
const a = ['Europe', 'Africa', 'Antarctica'];

const b = [
  { id: 11, warehouse_name: 'Europe', input_qty: 200, total_amt: 4000 },
  { id: 12, warehouse_name: 'Africa', input_qty: 150, total_amt: 3500 },
  { id: 13, warehouse_name: 'Africa', input_qty: 20, total_amt: 500 },
  { id: 14, warehouse_name: 'Antarctica', input_qty: 50, total_amt: 1500 },
];

const byWarehouse = _.groupBy(b, 'warehouse_name')

const result = a.map(warehouse_name => ({ warehouse_name, pack: byWarehouse[warehouse_name] }))

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```